# Issue while establishing connection with excel

Tags: excel, office-2007, office-2003, office-2010, vba

The below connection string establishes connection with excel file which has extension as '.xls' but same string throws an exception while opening a connection with file which has extension as .xlsx.

Any idea?

ConnectionString = Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=C:\Users\abcd\Desktop\demo.xls; Extended Properties=excel 8.0; Persist Security Info=False

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you need a [different connection string](http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel-2007) for xlsx'es.